# For all $n$, is there a real $n\times n$ matrix that can't be written as the sum of two commuting squares?

Tags: linear-algebra

My original problem was to prove that an even degree real polynomial which acts as a function from the set of real $n\times n$ matrices to itself cannot ever be surjective.

Now, I can negate the polynomial and add a real constant without changing its surjectivity, and since it's of even degree, I can make sure the polynomial is always positive. I have a previous result that says that any real polynomial that's always positive is the sum of two squares of real polynomials, so I'd like to show that, for all $n$, there's an $n\times n$ matrix that's not the sum of squares of two commuting (since they'd be polynomials of the same matrix) squares.

Is this actually true? For $n=2$, I tried $-I$, but of course, that's the sum of the squares of the $90$ degree rotation matrix and the zero matrix. So is this a good way to proceed, or should I try something else?

Comment: Hi Nishant. Do you want a matrix $A$  s.t.  $A\neq B^2+C^2$, for every $B,C$ that commute? When I read your question for the first time I understood that the condintion was $B^2$ and $C^2$ commute.

Comment: Yes, I want a matrix that cannot be written as the sum of commuting squares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the answer for your original problem. I don't know how to solve the second problem.

If a polynomial $p(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ has an even degree then $p(x)$ is not surjective. Thus, the image of $p(x)$ is not $\mathbb{R}$.

Now pick a diagonal matrix $A$ with distinct eigenvalues. Suppose exists $B$ such that $p(B)=A$. Thus, $B$ and $A$ commute, since A is a polynomial of $B$.

Since $A$ is diagonal with disctinct eigenvalues, $B$ must be diagonal too.

So the eigenvalues of $A$ belong to the image of $p(x)$.

Thus, if we pick a diagonal matrix $A$ with distinct eigenvalues and if one of this eigenvalues does not belong  to the image of $p(x)$ then there is no $B$ such that $p(B)=A$.

Comment: Yeah, I came up with a similar solution, but this one is more elegant. Mine was that every eigenvalue of $p(X)$ must be $p$ of some (possibly imaginary) eigenvalue of $X$, so just pick a diagonal matrix with $n$ distinct eigenvalues that are not in $p$'s image, and then the $X$ would have to have $2n$ eigenvalues (the preimages of the $n$ eigenvalues and their complex conjugates), a contradiction.